# Android Studio: create a style from an existing widget

Tags: android-studio, styles

I have a widget (a TextView) and want to extract its attributes as a style.
I could just write the style by hand, but when I have already created a widget with the style I want, it seems a bit silly to recreate it again in XML by hand.

Does anyone know the steps to take in Android Studio to create a style from an existing widget?

I'm pretty sure I've done this once before but have forgotten how.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the component, Refactor -> Extract Style